# In R output does not generate in sorted or preferred order

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a dataset with two different variables. A date column and a population count.  I used the following code to convert the date in my .csv to a date recognized by R and then sort my dataset. This code worked and the data was sorted in descending order. However, regardless of the sorting,  the output starts with the most recent date at the top of the graph. I would prefer the reverse with the date starting from the oldest date down to the most current. I understand this sounds like a descending order and that's what's in the code but without this code, the same order is generated (2015 down to the oldest date).  How can I get the output to match the dataset order is changed? Or, how can I reverse the order based on this output? Thank you!

```
library(ggplot2)

fp$Date1 <- as.Date(fp$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"); fp$Date1 

fp<-fp[order(as.Date(fp$Date1, format="%d/%m/%Y"), decreasing=TRUE),]

ggplot(data = fp[1:9,]) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Date1, y = WW, 
  size=20, col=Date1)) + 
  labs(x="Date", y="WW")+  
  coord_flip() +
 theme_bw()
```

After the conversion to Date1, this how the date column appears:

```
   Date1
1  2013-01-31
2  2013-04-30
3  2013-07-31
4  2013-10-31
5  2014-01-31
6  2014-04-30
7  2014-07-31
8  2014-10-31
9  2015-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the reverse function like thaT :

```
 fp<-fp[rev(order(as.Date(fp$Date1, format="%d/%m/%Y"))),]
```

**Explanation:**
By default the order function will order the result increasingly, so when you combine the rev function after applying the order function, it will revese the result.

Comment: Thank you, Ramy. This works to change the order of the data set. However, the plot order does not change, which is what I've been grappling with. After getting the dataset order, the output doesn't seem to change.